# Uploading an IMG file through RestSharp

Tags: c#, xamarin, restsharp

I have the code:

```
    request.AddFile ("image_request[image]", ("picture.jpg");
```

The "image_request[image]" is required for the specific API. The "picture.jpg" is in my /resources/ folder and correctly works.

However, with my application, I do not have a file stored locally. I take a picture with the camera app and have it stored as a photo called **img**, which I can convert to a .jpg

My question is: **How can I upload the file when I do not have a path?** I simply have the .jpg image stored in a variable. RestSharp asks for a string path as the second parameter in the method AddFile, however, as stated before, I do not have a path.

I want to be able to do something like

```
    request.AddFile ("image_request[image]", (img);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Path.GetTempFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[Path.GetTempPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettemppath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

It sounds like you may want to write the file to a temporary file, this would allow you to be in compliance with .AddFile's method signature

*EDIT*

```
//  Get an Image instance
Image image;
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    image = Image.FromStream(fs);
    //  Save to a temp file - this is the code that throws the exception
    image.Save(Path.GetTempFileName());
}
```

Comment: How do I write the img to the temporary file?